# Why does the SEO title in the typo3 backend determine my tab description?

Tags: typo3

In the typo3 backend you can set the 'page title' and the 'title for search engines'.
What you put into the 'page title' field will render as:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="myPageTitle">
```

What you put into the 'title for search engines' will render as:

```
<title>mySEOtitle</title>
```

Yet the title-tag also determines what text is displayed in your browser tab. Shouldn't the page title determine the browser tab text or what am I missing?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

IIRC it does - if you don't set an additional SEO title, the page title will be used for the title tag.

So it's up to you, if you want the title tag based on the original page title or if you want something different to be visible for search engines and end users there.